# ASP.NET Web API database not created in localdb

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have created an asp.net web api 4.5.2 project and I can't find the database that it's using for adding users. The info in the connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplicationTest2-20160906022916.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplicationTest2-20160906022916;Integrated Security=True.
```

But when I check the app_data directory it's empty. Where can I find this database?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Database creation for templates are delayed until a request  is sent.

Run your server and **POST** following JSON with `Content-Type: application/json` header to http://localhost:xxx/api/Account/Register:

```
{
  "Email": "test@test.com",
  "Password": "TestTest1!",
  "ConfirmPassword": "TestTest1!"
}
```

You should get `200: OK`.

I am using [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo).

[image: Advanced REST Client Chrome]

After that database will be created in `App_Data` folder. 
If server returned `200: OK` and `App_Data` is empty, Do the following steps:

In Visual Studio go to `View` menu. Select `SQL Server Object Explorer`(or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

Your SQL server should be there. You can find your database in `Databases` folder.

[image: Visual Studio View menu]
[image: SQL Server Object Explorer]

If you need *specifically* the **data file**, then expand `Databases` folder, right click on which one you need and click on `Properties`. Scroll down to see `Current Connection Parameters`.

[image: Properties]

Comment: Hi Orkhan, thank you for your answer. I checked the database as you suggested. The problem is that I don't see the database there? It looks like it doesn't exists. When I try to connect to it, the database server tells me that it can't attache the file. Is there a way to generate this database through scripts?

Comment: Right click on database server starting with **(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDb...** and choose **New Query**, write `create database MyDatabase`, then execute. You'll need to refresh Server Object Explorer to see created database. To get connection string to newly created database, rightclick on it and open up Properties window, there you will see Connection String of that database

Comment: Or right click on *Databases* click `Add New Database`

Comment: Well I know how to create a database. I ment what's the database model of the database used in api? How can I generate the database to be ready to use for the api.

Comment: Did you created an empty project or a template? For an empty project, you have to create nothing until you need.

Comment: I did create a template: New project -> ASP.net Web Application -> Web API with Individual User accounts authorization.

Comment: yes that worked very good. Thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Some times this error occurred when you do not install local db of SQL server.To know if you install local db,open command prompt(administrator) and type  "SqlLocalDb info".Then it show localdb name.add that name into connection string.If command prompt is not show this,refer following link to add localdb into SQL express server.
link:-https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5612/getting-started-with-sql-server-2017-express-localdb/